# Que tal uma tag que sinalize a necessidade de interação da SE em uma discussão do Meta?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, tag-específica

Muito sentimos pela falta da presença do pessoal da SE de maneira ativa aqui no Meta. Muita discussão interessante fica no limbo porque a comunidade não tem autoridade para fazer o necessário. Ter uma resposta oficial por parte dos responsáveis pelo site é sempre interessante.

Concordo que isso deveria ser natural no Meta. Mas não é e a culpa é da própria SE. Muitas vezes, quando vejo que a discussão pode tomar um rumo interessante eu encaminho o link diretamente ao Nicolas. Nem isso tem funcionado. Toda vez que questiono-o quando irá responder as perguntas ele me responde alguma variação de "*oi, tudo bem? seria legal me enviar os links das perguntas que julga ser interessante eu responder*".

Questionei a ele se haveria como existir uma tag que se utilizada no Meta automaticamente o notificasse da pergunta para que pudesse ser utilizada em perguntas que não são questões internas da comunidade e realmente seria interessante um parecer deles. A resposta foi que poderíamos criar uma tag qualquer e repassá-la para que ele possa *se inscrever* na mesma.

> *Hi @Woss! It is an interesting idea, thank you! Any tag works fine to me. Please pick one and let me know which one I should subscribe for. On the other hand you can ping me or my colleagues here any time you think we need to look at something (and probably missed it).*

<sup>https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53156329#53156329</sup>

Para não virar uma bagunça completa, acredito que o ideal é que a tag seja exclusiva de moderadores, para que eles possam avaliar se a discussão realmente demanda a interação direta da SE no debate ou não (para evitar coisas como "por que minha pergunta foi fechada?" utilizando a tag).

Mas, para facilitar também a moderação e evitar que sempre que alguém criar uma pergunta interessante ter que solicitar aos moderadores a adição da tag, poderia existir uma segunda tag como auxiliar, livre para a comunidade, que indicasse a moderação que a pergunta necessita de uma análise sobre a tag original (semelhante a que ocorre com a [proposta-para-faq](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq)).

A título de exemplo, existir as tags [requer-interação-se](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requer-intera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-se), exclusiva da moderação, e [possivelmente-requer-interação-se](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/possivelmente-requer-intera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-se), livre para a comunidade. A moderação, ao analisar a pergunta, altera a tag ou a remove, conforme a conclusão da análise.

Eu sinceramente não acho que isso irá resolver o problema. Eles serão notificados e provavelmente ignorarão como sempre, mas talvez valha a tentativa.

O que acham? Se sim, quais os nomes para as tags?

Comment: Como novo recurso com essas característica duvido que vá rolar, e acho que por ser exceção o *ping* já funcionaria, só precisa criar um protocolo com eles para que seja cumprido.

Comment: @Maniero O recurso já existe. Basta criar a tag e manda-lo pro Nicolas se inscrever no "ping" dela. Salvo engano, a única que funciona assim hoje é a [tag:bug], não?

Comment: Boa ideia, não custa tentar.

Comment: Não existe porque eles teria que fazer a *tag* agir assim e eles não fazem, inclusive porque o site que conta eles não precisam disto e o que é feito vale pra todos os sites. Poderia ter uma *tag* normal, que poderia ser abusada. Eu nem sei se `bug` eles olham, a não ser de tempos em tempos. Eu acho que só pingar externamente já resolve o problema se eles se dispuseram olhar sempre. Até porque se isto não acontecer a *tag* não ajudará. E o foi respondido no *chat* já dá indiciações que pouco funcionará. Esse meta é pra comunidade, se quisermos falar com a SE terá que ser no metão,é a realidade

Comment: @Maniero Se entendi bem, o Nicolas tem como configurar para ser "pingado" em uma determinada tag. "*Please pick one and let me know which one I should subscribe for.*"

Comment: Ser pingado sim, todo mundo pode fazer isso em qualquer tag, mas não ser algo só de moderador, isto tem que programar no código e não vão fazer. A questão é que qualquer ping resolve se eles cumprirem e algo excepcional assim não acho que precisa de algo especial na comunidade ou no sistema, até porque é a exceção.

Comment: Ah, você se referia a tag exclusiva da moderação. Não tinha entendido essa parte :D